# Jquery File Upload plugin in django

Tags: django, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to use jQuery file upload plugin to upload files
I am having a form containing  text field and other inputs as well as the fileupload plugin specified file input as below

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'compose' %}" id="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="t1"/>
    <input data-bfi-disabled='' multiple='' name='files[]' type='file'>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in Django view I am trying to access the files uploaded with the following

```
attachment = request.FILES.getlist("files[]")
```

But on submit clicking I am getting blank filelist.
Where am I doing wrong?
I dont need ajax submission of individual files.
I need to submit all files upload along with other input contents to the view.

UPDATE:
   when I checked in the UI by removing css classes of file upload button i could see "No FILE CHOSEN" but I could see list of files  like below

[image: file upload screen shot]

I am confused how to use this plugin to submit my form with the selected files and other fields

Comment: Why is the field named `files[]` and not just `files`? If you dump `request.FILES` in Django, does it contain anything, or is it empty? If you observe the request in Firebug (or any browser developer tool), does the request goes through successfuly? Where did you take the jQuery plugin you are talking about?

Comment: [Here](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) is the source for fileupload API .We can use files[] as well as files 1st one has advantage when using PHP.

Comment: Right, but you are using Python serverside, so what's the point of adding a workaround for PHP? What about my other questions?

Comment: When I checked in django debug mode i am getting empty request.FILES in django

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Form models:

`class FileUploadForm(forms.Form):
    file_source = forms.FileField()`

Then:

```
<form action="/upload/" method="post" id="file-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='upload-btn'>Upload</button>
```

And your view:

```
def upload_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = FileUploadForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print 'valid form'
```

Comment: I need to use File upload API because I need functionality like selecting multiple files  from single folder as well as multiple folders with a single file input usage